# Powershell issue - Cannot acess my Desktop inside user\documents folder

Tags: powershell, directory, settings, desktop

I am currently taking google IT certifications and in the section for becoming a power user for powershell and linux. Im stuck at this one point where im trying to figure out why I cannot follow what she is doing in the video. she is trying to copy a file from documents to desktop but every time I even try to access the Desktop using the tilde or any other method it will not do anything. Im not sure what im doing wrong

```
PS C:\Users\chaos\Documents> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\chaos\Documents


    Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                 -------------         ------ ----
    d-----          9/9/2023  12:03 PM                mycoolfile.txt
    -a----          5/1/2017   1:26 PM          31423 Cover letter Prototype.docx
    -a----         1/29/2017   4:48 PM          11510 Document 1.docx


PS C:\Users\chaos\Documents> cp mycoolfile.txt C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\
cp : Cannot create "C:\Users\chaos\Desktop" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ cp mycoolfile.txt C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

PS C:\Users\chaos\Documents> cd ~\Desktop
cd : Cannot find path '~\Desktop' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd ~\Desktop
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (~\Desktop:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Im not sure if this is an outdated video and maybe there is a new way to do this that im not aware of if im causing the issue myself. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do a `Get-ChildItem -Path ~` and see what comes up.  Is it possible that the Desktop folder location has been moved somewhere else?  You can verify your Desktop folder location by typing `[System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')`.  If you're not already using a lab enviornment, I recommend using the Windows Sandbox optional feature or a VM when experimenting/learning.  This helps a lot when you get to PowerShell remoting and/or setting up a domain lab.

Comment: `(New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace( "shell:ThisPCDesktopFolder" ).Self. Path` -- (.OneDrive, perhaps... )

Answer (score 0):

Your symptoms imply two anomalies in your environment:

- `C:\Users\chaos\Desktop` is a *file* rather than a directory.
- Conversely, `mycoolfile.txt` is a *directory* rather than a file.